# The application does not start on the ios simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm working on a react native app with firebase, the app works great on android, but everytime I try to start the dev server for ios simulator I get this error.
I initialized my application with Expo bare workflow, and I followed all the configurations for setting up the development environment from the official react native site and I also followed all the firebase configurations from the rnfirebase.io
I need help

```
❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:109:38)

  107 |   func readAndWriteAsync(using transform: @escaping (HeartbeatsBundle?) -> HeartbeatsBundle?) {
  108 |     queue.async { [self] in
> 109 |       let oldHeartbeatsBundle = try? load(from: storage)
      |                                      ^ call to method 'load' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
  110 |       let newHeartbeatsBundle = transform(oldHeartbeatsBundle)
  111 |       try? save(newHeartbeatsBundle, to: storage)
  112 |     }


❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:109:49)

  107 |   func readAndWriteAsync(using transform: @escaping (HeartbeatsBundle?) -> HeartbeatsBundle?) {
  108 |     queue.async { [self] in
> 109 |       let oldHeartbeatsBundle = try? load(from: storage)
      |                                                 ^ reference to property 'storage' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
  110 |       let newHeartbeatsBundle = transform(oldHeartbeatsBundle)
  111 |       try? save(newHeartbeatsBundle, to: storage)
  112 |     }


❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:111:12)

  109 |       let oldHeartbeatsBundle = try? load(from: storage)
  110 |       let newHeartbeatsBundle = transform(oldHeartbeatsBundle)
> 111 |       try? save(newHeartbeatsBundle, to: storage)
      |            ^ call to method 'save' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
  112 |     }
  113 |   }
  114 | 


❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:111:42)

  109 |       let oldHeartbeatsBundle = try? load(from: storage)
  110 |       let newHeartbeatsBundle = transform(oldHeartbeatsBundle)
> 111 |       try? save(newHeartbeatsBundle, to: storage)
      |                                          ^ reference to property 'storage' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
  112 |     }
  113 |   }
  114 | 

› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal » RingBuffer.swift
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal » _ObjC_HeartbeatController.swift
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal » HeartbeatController.swift
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal » HeartbeatsBundle.swift
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal » Heartbeat.swift
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » SysUio.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » FileUtil.cpp
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » NetOps.cpp
› Packaging @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/GoogleDataTransport » libGoogleDataTransport.a
› Packaging react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » libRCT-Folly.a
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/auth Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics » FIRCoreDiagnostics.m
    Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Gocoinet editor. (in target 'Gocoinet' from project 'Gocoinet')

› 4 error(s), and 1 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
```